# How to connect to vonage wirelessly?

Tags: networking, router, ethernet

I am moving my modem/router setting (cable high-speed Internet) upstairs because I am setting up a server there and I need Ethernet there. My only problem is, I need my vonage phone downstairs. Vonage generally connects to your router/modem. Can I connect that `wirelessly`?

Comment: Vonage, or any VoIP device for that matter, just need to connect to the network at some point, not specifically the router. If you bridge the two areas using wireless bridges, it will work. There are many many questions on SU for wireless bridging.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not very familiar with Vonage and I have not done any setups like this, but I assume your Vonage device right now is connected with a regular ethernet cable to your router. If that's the case, then the only thing you need is a wireless bridge, e.g.:

- Cisco-Linksys-WET11-Wireless-Ethernet-Bridge
- ASUS RT-N12 Wireless-N Router, Access Point, and Repeater

or something along these lines, depending on your budget.

Here's a nice page that describes using DD-WRT to do the same:

- http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/how-to-turn-an-old-router-into-a-wireless-bridge/

and obviously you need some of the routers from the list of supported devices from here:

- http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Supported_Devices

Also take a look at this link for some tweaking of WRT54G:

- http://forums.anandtech.com/showthread.php?t=1115